# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot have circular references in bean class but got the circular reference of class java.time.ZoneOffset

Tags: java, apache-spark, offsetdatetime

While executing the below command

`StructType obs = Encoders.bean(Test.class).schema();`

I am getting the below error

`java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot have circular references in bean class, but got the circular reference of class class java.time.ZoneOffset`

class Test has `OffsetDateTime` field, which is causing the error. If I remove this field the error also goes away.
Is there a way by which I can avoid this circular reference error and also use OffsetDateTime?

````
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot have circular references in bean class, but got the circular reference of class class java.time.ZoneOffset
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.cannotHaveCircularReferencesInBeanClassError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:984)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.inferDataType(JavaTypeInference.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.$anonfun$inferDataType$1(JavaTypeInference.scala:156)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:286)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:36)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach$(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:198)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:286)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:279)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.inferDataType(JavaTypeInference.scala:154)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.inferDataType(JavaTypeInference.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.$anonfun$inferDataType$1(JavaTypeInference.scala:156)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:286)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:36)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach$(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:198)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:286)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:279)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.inferDataType(JavaTypeInference.scala:154)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.$anonfun$inferDataType$1(JavaTypeInference.scala:156)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:286)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:36)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach$(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:198)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:286)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:279)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.inferDataType(JavaTypeInference.scala:154)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.$anonfun$inferDataType$1(JavaTypeInference.scala:156)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:286)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:36)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach$(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:198)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:286)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:279)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.inferDataType(JavaTypeInference.scala:154)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.$anonfun$inferDataType$1(JavaTypeInference.scala:156)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:286)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:36)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach$(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:198)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:286)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:279)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.inferDataType(JavaTypeInference.scala:154)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.inferDataType(JavaTypeInference.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder$.javaBean(ExpressionEncoder.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders$.bean(Encoders.scala:171)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.bean(Encoders.scala)```
````

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## `OffsetDateTime` not supported by `Encoders`

As per `Encoder` [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Encoders.html#bean-java.lang.Class-), supported type for bean fields are:

> supported types for java bean field: - primitive types: boolean, int,
> double, etc. - boxed types: Boolean, Integer, Double, etc. - String -
> java.math.BigDecimal, java.math.BigInteger - time related:
> java.sql.Date, java.sql.Timestamp, java.time.LocalDate,
> java.time.Instant - collection types: array, java.util.List, and map -
> nested java bean.

So it looks like it may not be possible to use `OffsetDateTime` as far as I can see.
`ZoneOffset` is part of `OffsetDateTime` field so call `Encoders.bean` might be generating code which keeps referring `ZoneOffset` in circular manner.

## Use `Instant`

You can convert a `OffsetDateTime` object to the more basic class, [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html).

```
Instant instant = odt.toInstant() ;
```

And back again.

```
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.ofHours( -8 ) ;
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( offset ) ;
```